# MS SQL how to record negative time

Tags: c#, .net

I have a column in the MS SQL database with type “TIME”. I need to record a negative value in it. It isn't a range between two certain times or dates. It’s an abstract value of time that is used in calculations. In the entity framework it is treated as a TimeSpan, which MetaData.tt does automatically with all TIME defined columns in the database.

For example, I might have an arbitrary calendar with events at 5AM and 8PM on Monday, one at 4PM on Tuesday, and one at 3AM on the Sunday after that. I could add the value to these times and get a time either before (in case of negative time), or after (in case of positive time) the beginning of the event.

When I try to write down a negative value, the database refuses it.

The recording of entity to database goes by direct bind of post attributes in the controller, so if it needs to be translated into ticks, is it reliable to do so in Javascript? How would I go about the input textbox for it? It looks like I cannot separate the value from the content in a text box. And if I have to turn it into an INT, I cannot use @EditorFor on it anymore, creating another point of fault where code becomes less flexible.

It almost feels like I should create new columns to denote the negativity of these values and use a dropdown list with hidden inputs instead of a textbox.

EDIT:
Why avoid non-time types:

Consider this code:

```
var typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetadataProperties.Where(…).FirstOrDefault());
```

If the EDM property has the type int, the generated code will be the type int.
The EDM property comes from the database itself, so if it is not a type that translates directly into a time, then there will need to be a new method (somewhere in a helper, perhaps), which translates this into a time. This new method will have to be maintained (by other people on the team), which means a weak point, because if someone changes the column name, now the code will not just get properly generated again.

Errors may also not be available through the error log, since most properties also tend to be referenced in javascript at some point (which is often also generated, and now can't be for this column because it is a special case). I'm also talking about some 20 columns suffering from this, so this has a very good potential to quickly turn into a deeply tangled ball of spaghetti.

Comment: `time` is a time of day, not a duration.

Comment: So what is the native MS SQL column data type which can store durations that natively translate into a TimeSpan in the entity framework? Automatically generated edmx, data models, entities, linq, controllers, et alia.

Comment: Please choose one specific scenario in your code that illustrates why an integer duration won't work and include it in your post.

Comment: @mbeckish Please see the updated question with an example of code  where using improper types can go wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really seems like you are trying to store a duration, not a time. `TIME` is used for storing a point in time, not an amount of time.  I would choose some subdivision of time (second, millisecond, etc), and store that as an `int` (or `bigint` if necessary).  Then in SQL Server you could use `DATEADD(SECOND,@storedValue,@dateToChange)` to calculate the true time or `DateTime.Add.Milliseconds(storedValue)` or `DateTime.Add.Seconds(storedValue)`, so on, in C# when trying to calculate the time you want.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Strictly speaking I'm trying to store a time offset value, rather than a duration, but these things can be treated the same. I can manage it as an int, but what do I need to screw around to make my EDMX generator and code generators to translate it into a TimeSpan? Can I use Javascript to convert input value in hh:mm:ss format to ticks without generating discrepancies?

Comment: Ahh, yeah offset is a better term.  If you're looking for an int to hold seconds offset, you could use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()` on the int result from DB to generate your timespan.  `FromMilliseconds()`, `FromMinutes()`, `FromHours()`, and `FromDays()`

Comment: I got side-tracked merging a large branch of changes and sorting out glitches, so I didn't bring this to the end yet. I went to the application's architect, and he said we'll use a dropdown of pre-defined increments instead of a textbox since this is what is used in other major applications in the field, so I ended up translating this to an integer. Here's the deeper problem I'll have to sort: typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetaDataProperties.Where(…).FirstOrDefault()); In this metadata.tt piece, the type is grabbed by escaping the database code itself, requires special case for this.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I think I would store both Begin and End times and have another Computed Column to store the difference (with INT datatype) using DATEDIFF:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  Time1 time
  Time2 time
  timedifference AS DATEDIFF(Second, Time1,Time2)
);
```

Then you can convert the Seconds into a time of day like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, timedifference * 1000, 0), 114)
```

Here is a working sample of what you will get:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(Second, CAST('12:24:18.3500000' as time),CAST('11:24:18.3500000' as time)) * 1000, 0), 114)

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(Second, CAST('11:24:18.3500000' as time),CAST('12:24:18.3500000' as time)) * 1000, 0), 114)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. I'm trying to record specifically a time offset. to use in calculations at runtime.

Consider use case scenario:
This entity I am talking about can be called “Warning”. Now I might have set up this warning to have a -15 minute offset, meaning that if I attach it to an event, this warning happens 15 minutes before the event start.

So:
new Event event("8am 13 Nov 2015");
event.add(db.Warnings.Find("Begins soon"));

Will create an entry with three columns as opposed to an entry with two columns. Now imagine that fifty million times over for fifty million events.

Comment: @Nomenator Yeah, so you keep the value as an INT value (As seconds or milliseconds) and then convert that to a Time with the last query i put up here ...

Answer (score 1):

Database type `time` does not support negative values. The acceptable range is `00:00:00.0000000` through `23:59:59.9999999`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx